# If one of the 4 elements is a 9 return true, if not return false

Tags: python, list, function

Sample Input---------[1,2,9,4,5]
Sample Input----------[1,2,4,5]

Expected Output--------True
Expected Output-------------------False

This was my code that I written(my problem is that it keeps return false no matter what)

```
def find_nine(nums):
    if "9" in nums:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    

nums=[1,9,4,5,6]
print(find_nine(nums))
```

Comment: Your list has integers.  Your function checks for a string.  These can *never* be equal.  Make up your mind what you're searching for.  Close as a typo.

Comment: I think this is worth keeping open as an example, but there's surely a suitable duplicate out there.

Comment: @prune how do I close the question?

Comment: Simply delete it.  Details for these manipulations are in the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) you worked through when you signed up for your account.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between `"9"` (which is a string) and `9` (which is an integer). Modify your code to use the latter and you're golden.

Also, whenever you have the pattern

```py
if bool:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

you should replace it with

```py
return bool
```

Final code:

```py
def find_nine(nums):
    return 9 in nums
```